# Enable-PSRemoting or Set-WSManQuickConfig?

Tags: powershell, dsc, remoting

I'm getting pumped up for DSC and I want to cover my bases. I see that Enable-PSRemoting actually runs Set-WSManQuickConfig according to help documentation, I guess my main question is, what is the difference between the two? Looks like newer documentation whether it be a book or online article only mentions Enable-PSRemoting and not necessarily Set-WSManQuickConfig. Is Enable-PSRemoting just newer/better? Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK they are more or less the same.  I have no proof, but I think  `Enable-PSRemoting` is suggested and used because the name of the commandlet is a lot more obvious, and easy to remember.

Comment: `winrm /qc` is what I use

Answer (score 4):

Checked the help documentation of the two cmdlets.

Set-WSManQuickConfig performs the following:

> -- Checks whether the WinRM service is running. If the WinRM service is not running, the service is started.
>
> -- Sets the WinRM service startup type to automatic.
>
> -- Creates a listener to accept requests on any IP address. By default, the transport is HTTP.
>
> -- Enables a firewall exception for WinRM traffic .

Enable-PSRemoting also does the above, and additionally:

> ----- Registers the Microsoft.PowerShell and Microsoft.PowerShell.Workflow session configurations, if it they are
>   not already registered.
>
> ----- Registers the Microsoft.PowerShell32 session configuration on 64-bit computers, if it is not already registered.
>
> ----- Enables all session configurations.
>
> ----- Changes the security descriptor of all session configurations to allow remote access.
>
> ----- Restarts the WinRM service to make the preceding changes effective.

So `Enable-PSRemoting` is the one to use unless you intend on manually configuring sessions.

Comment: Thanks @Deadly-Bagel, and everyone! Very helpful information.

Comment: WinRM is the underlying transport for remote PowerShell, WMI, and CIM.  The PowerShell specific items are layered on top of that basis.